# Add loading div till data loads while editing angular Form

Tags: angular

Here is code for spinner card:

```
<ng-template #spinnercard>
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-title>Loading</mat-card-title>
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
</ng-template>
```

Here is my simple form code:

```
<form (submit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="markupForm">    
        <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="markup_flatrate" matInput placeholder="Flat Rate Markup"  />
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
            <input formControlName="markup_percent" matInput placeholder="Markup Percent"   />
        </mat-form-field>

        <button [disabled]="!markupForm.valid" color="primary" mat-raised-button [class.spinner]="loading" [disabled]="loading" >
          <span *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
        Save Changes</button>
    </form>
```

Here is the code for fetching form values:

```
     this.markupsSvc.getMarkupRuleDetails(this.client, this.rule_id)
                    .pipe(first())
                    .subscribe(x => {this.markupForm.patchValue(x); 
                  });
```

The issue is it takes lot of time to load the form values and I want to add the spinnercard/loading div till the time form values are not loaded. Please help.

Comment: Put this Observable `this.markupsSvc.getMarkupRuleDetails(this.client, this.rule_id).pipe(first())` in a variable `obs$` then use NgIfElse directive with asyn pipe `*ngIf="obs$ | async"` in the from element.

Comment: I am using the same form for add and edit both. So if I take the observable as u suggested then what will happen in case of 'Add'?

Comment: Then add a creation case in the NgIfElse  `creating || obs$ | async`.

Comment: It works fine in case of edit but keeps loading in Add case.<div *ngIf="creating || markup$ | async as markup else spinnercard">